# How to disable permalink of a particular menu item?

Tags: menus, permalinks

I'm using WordPress Twenty Sixteen theme. Now I've a menu item named Product and it has a sub menu. The product page has a permalink as usual, but I want to remove it i.e., when I click on this menu item, it shouldn't perform any action, just like clicking on a text. However, it should not lose its hover color while doing so.

I found a solution pointer-events: none, but it removes the hover color. I don't want to use JavaScript/jQuery.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: Making a menu item that links to `#` will cause the link going nowhere.

Comment: It will lead the user to top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

How about just go to the menu from wp-admin remove product menu(i.e the current one) now create a new menu (Product)using Custom Menu and put url to # and add ur sub menus, 
if u have different class for current menu u can add custom class too follow these steps
In Appearance > Menus, click the Screen Options tab.
Under Show advanced menu properties, check CSS Classes.
Now expand any menu item to reveal the CSS Classes (optional) text input

thanks

Comment: Do you mean "using Custom Links" instead of "using Custom Menu". You should not need to change anything in CSS classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with PHP then use a [custom walker](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker#General_Menu_Example) and targeting the menu directly (if is menu item xxx), but jQuery will do this easily for you using removeAttr

```
$("#menu-item-xxx"). removeAttr("href");
```

That won't remove the  tag, just removes the href="" from the tag.

Comment: It'll be really better to do that in PHP instead of JS... In JS Google will follow  the link of the deactivated page!

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly, I prefer use filters to manipulate data before menu generation.

Example with `wp_setup_nav_menu_item`:

```
add_filter('wp_setup_nav_menu_item', function($menu) {
    $menu->url = "";
    return $menu;
});
```

This filter is ran on each retrieved menu item but without nowing which menu is currently processed.

Another example with `wp_get_nav_menu_items` :

```
add_filter('wp_get_nav_menu_items', function($items, $menu) {
    if( $menu->slug === 'menu-principal' ) {
        foreach ($items as &$item) {
            if ($item->ID === 'MY-PRODUCT-PAGE-ID') {
                $item->url = "";
            }
        }
    }
    return $items;
}, 10, 2);
```

This other filter is ran after all the menu items have been retrieved. You can also access the current menu Term details in the `$menu` variable (be sure to give 2 as the latest `add_filter` argument to retrieve menu details).

The default "walker" take care of the `url` property value to adapt HTML structure and behaviour. I think it can solve your problem.